# The Obsever pattern (or something similar) using a global update() function in C++?

Tags: c++

I am creating an MVC application in C++ and I want the lower level model classes to be able to update the GUI with simple text to display output to the reader. I don't want to have to pass around function or object pointers as it would get messy and I would have to pass them around all over the place. What I essentially want is the equivalent to 'cout' for a console GUI - some sort of global function that can be called to update the GUI from anywhere without having to know anything about the GUI.

I've mentioned the Observer pattern in the title because it sounds a lot like that - the GUI could subscribe to this global object or function in someway and listen for when it is called. However, I'm not specifically looking for a solution using Observer.

People have mentioned signals and slots to me but surely, unless global, you are still required to 'pass things around' to allow objects to emit the signals. Again, a global point of reference would be helpful.

How can I do this while ensuring that good design principles are adhered to?

Comment: If you want to adhere to good design principles, then you *want* to pass things around.

Comment: @sftrabbit So passing a function pointer to this update(string) method would be OK? It just seems a bit messy if you have 50+ classes that need to write to the GUI say and have to pass the same function pointer to all of them. Granted, my application doesn't have 50 classes but design principles still apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems appropriate to use Observer pattern here. However, I think you have a few mistakes here. You need to clearly define the roles of each participating party. I would suggest the following partition: the GUI is the observer (i.e., listener) and lower level objects are the ones signaling the changes to the listener. Upon initialization the lower-level module will register itself with the GUI (observer). Once the change occurs, the lower-level module will execute the public listening handler of the observer providing the needed data as input.

This will allow you to achieve your goal and no globals are involved in the scheme.

Comment: But this still requires passing things around by the sound of it...upon initialization the model objects must be passed a reference to the GUI to be able to subscribe to it - or am I missing the point?

Comment: Yes, it has. But that's exactly the point. All you need to pass to your model is the registration and handler API. It's part of the public interface of GUI, internals needn't (and shouldn't) be known by the model.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I guess it does seem tidier to pass the registration and handler API to only the objects that should be allowed to use them. As I am using a single GUI (observer) would there be any need for the Observer pattern as this seems more geared towards multiple observers listening in on a single subject. Or have I misunderstood again?

Comment: Actually, single observer is the natural situation. Observer pattern is just a label for a concept/behavior (what I've described), you don't need to force upon your code anything predefined, such as external library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stdout` and `stderr` to do this. Just redirect output from them to your application. The simpliest possible solution - redirect application output to file and use `tail -f redirected_output_file_name` to see updates.

Or otherwise you can use `log4cxx`, you need to implement custom appender in this case.

Comment: I would like to use a function I created rather than one of these, and then linking them back to my GUI. Just seems a bit hacky.

Comment: It's not "hacky". Standard input/output is built into runtime for reason.